# How can I upload a file using JavaScript without a postback?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, upload

I am working on a file upload in ASP.NET. I used `<input type=file id=upload>` and `<input type=button id="btnupload" value="File Upload">`

I want to upload the file in JavaScript. The update panel does not work, I do not want it to postback and refresh the page.

thanks but If you have code related to fileUpload in javascript then send me. please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery and [jQuery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). I used this combination for few project and i had no problems, even for big files (10mb)

```
<form action="form.asp" method="post">
.......
</form>
$('form').submit(function(){
 $(this).ajaxSubmit(function(data){
  $('#updateDiv').html(data); // or append/prepend/whatever
 })
 return false
})
```

Ofcourse, the action of the form will return what you need to update. You may want to add some extra functions to handle errors, but this should work fine

Comment: thanks lonut Staicu, But if you give me some example which I can understand properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio 2008 (or has ajax installed in 05) then wrap an update panel arround your input fields, this will make the postback asynchronously using javascript (ajax).

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Is it work in Inner Update pannel? Because I allready used Upper Updatepannel, thanks.

Comment: do you mean an update panel within another update panel? ..because then i don't think it will make a different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the "proper" way to do it using ASP.NET, but generally you'll want your form, and a hidden iframe that the form posts to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleUploadResponse(...) {
        // do something...
    }
</script>
<form method="post" action="upload.aspx" target="hiddenframe" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
<iframe id="hiddenframe" name="hiddenframe" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

When you submit the form, this will post to whatever script will handle the upload in the hidden frame. When complete, the hidden frame's page calls `window.parent.handleUploadResponse(...);` which calls the `handleUploadResponse()` function on the parent page that initiated the upload.

Comment: Matt Berseth has an upload component similar to what you are describing.  http://tinyurl.com/acu3hc

Comment: thanks but if you give me their brief example then I can understand Properly, If you have any link related to that then also send me. Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

use jquery form plugin for the upload functionality (http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/)
use ( http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/) for the ability to specify multiple files to upload

this is how it works, the form plugin lets you post data to a page without refreshing, the multi file plugin lets you specify multiple files by browsing for them.

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="FileHandler.ashx">
<input type="hidden" value="100000" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"/>
File:
<input type="file" name="file"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

so basically the above little html submits to FileHandler.ashx, whatever's in the input box (hopefully), add an HTTP handler in ur asp project, little code below

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="FileHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

public class FileHandler : IHttpHandler
{

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(context.Request.Files[0].FileName);
string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(context.Request.Files[0].FileName).ToLower();
string strSaveLocation = context.Server.MapPath("Upload") + "" + strFileName;
context.Request.Files[0].SaveAs(strSaveLocation);

context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
context.Response.Write("success");
}

public bool IsReusable
{
get
{
return false;
}
}
}
```

all thats missing from here is including the js scripts on ur aspx page, i think :) good luck

Comment: when i did this i find it do postback i need to post the file without postback ???

Comment: kindly i need to know it in javascript pure

Comment: I tried the same code but got context.Request.Files.Count = 0. any idea why?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to prevent the page from being refreshed, send a `204 No Content` HTTP header.