# upload image file without post back in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does anybody know how can I upload an image file in a specific folder without post back
using c# .

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527955/how-can-i-upload-a-file-using-javascript-without-a-postback and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797190/file-uploading-in-ajax-updatepanel-without-full-postback

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this. But you can accomplish it using AJAX. Take a look at jquery and some it's plugins, for example [jQuery File Upload Plugin](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-file-upload-plugin/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use flash and an HttpHandler to prevent the requirement for a postback.

I have use this example in the past: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FlashUpload.aspx