# Try To Display Image onChange Event of Input File

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I m trying to display image after selecting it directly on the `onchange` event of an input file i figure it out how it done in all browsers but i stopped by safari i m trying to get the

`inputFile.value` property but it returns me a fake path i neeeeeeeed help even with a walk around that issue but i don't need a post back.

Regards

Comment: So you're asking us to correct your code without showing it?

Comment: no its not like that all am asking is a solution for a fakepath returns i make up a search every where but i found nothing

Comment: I wonder why you're getting only in Safari a fake path since even IE returns only the file-name since version 7. http://rattomago.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/accessing-filepath-in-html-input-element-via-javascript/ Is it an intranet or internet application?

Comment: in IE 8 yes but in 9 i find the full path is a simple internet app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268889/retrieving-the-full-path-server-side-of-a-file-uploaded-using-firefox

Comment: I Sow a jquery plugin did it but i dont know is it working around i will find it and comeback to discuss

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527955/how-can-i-upload-a-file-using-javascript-without-a-postback

Guys see this link jquery do it i with to know how to do it in pure javascript

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your input and image are as under

```
<img id="PreviewImage" src="" alt="?" style="height:100px;"  />
<input id="ImageFileUpload" onchange="readURL(this);" type="file" runat="server"/>

function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {//Check if input has files.
var reader = new FileReader(); //Initialize FileReader.

reader.onload = function (e) {
$('#PreviewImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
$("#PreviewImage").resizable({ aspectRatio: true, maxHeight: 300 });
};
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
} 
else {
$('#PreviewImage').attr('src', "#");
}
}
```

Comment: may be works in some browsers but not in every FileReader is not compatable with all browsers